# Deleting really exact duplicates

Tags: discussion, moderation, duplicates

There has just been a [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5541/) which was [repeated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5543/) almost immediately due to a user account issue. In general, we've agreed not to delete or merge duplicate questions, but in this case the two versions don't add anything at all (I think). Would a bit of moderator 'cleaning up' be appropriate here?

Comment: sure, in this case there is no point in having both questions. Btw, its the same user id for both questions, so i don't understand what the problem was.

Comment: @Caramdir: It wasn't half an hour ago! I've already done the merge on the two user IDs.

Comment: ok, didn’t know that you could do that (because otherwise I would have suggested merging the other way so that the user stays in control of the question).

Comment: Seems a clear-cut case to me.  But I recommend waiting 24hrs just to see if anyone stops by with a killer argument for keeping it.

Comment: Mind you, deletes aren't forever, so we could just delete it and see if anyone complains!

Comment: @Caramdir: The merge went the way it did as the first ID was 'unregistered' and the second was 'registered'. So the decision on direction was really made for me! As I understand it, the resulting single user ID should end up in charge of any questions which were written using either of the original ones.

Comment: @joseph: i meant that the questions, i.e. that the first question should be closed and not the second one. But since you merged the users it doesn't matter which question is kept.

Comment: @Caramdir: My working assumption was that it made logical sense to a) merge the users and b) keep the 'parent' question if possible. I may of course be wrong.

Comment: No, you are right. May comment was just about the hypothetical case that merging of users is impossible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, it seems like the best answer here is:

1. Flag up that one of the questions will be deleted
2. Wait 24 hours for any objections
3. Actually do the deleting